# Legendrian knot in 3-sphere

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, 4-manifolds, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry, legendrian-submanifolds

We are given a Legendrian knot, fixed up to Legendrian isotopy, in $(S^3,\xi)$    ($\xi$ is the standard contact structure). Does it necessarily bound a symplectic surface in $(B^4,\omega)$ (again $\omega$ is the standard symplectic structure)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are obstructions to this.

Suppose $L$ is a Legendrian knot that bounds a symplectic surface $\Sigma$, and $T$ a (sufficiently close) transverse push-off (see Etnyre's [notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306256) or Geiges' *Introduction to contact topology* for references). Notice that $T$ can be chosen to be $C^\infty$-arbitrarily close to $L$. (This is clear from the construction, although I couldn't find a clean statement in a quick search.)

You can perturb $\Sigma$ along with $K$ while keeping it symplectic, so that it bounds $T$. Now take the double cover of the ball, branched along $T$: this gives a symplectic 4-manifold whose (strongly convex) boundary is the branched cover of the standard contact 3-sphere along $T$. Hence the branched double cover of $\xi$ along $T$ is (strongly) symplectically fillable.

There are plenty of transverse knots whose branched cover is overtwisted, e.g. if $T$ is transverse stabilisation (see, for example, Harvey, Kawamuro, Plamenevskaya, [*On transverse knots and branched cover*](http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2009/3/512.abstract), which makes for a very pleasant read). To be even more concrete, take the unknot with Thurston-Bennequin number -3 and rotation number 0: this cannot bound a symplectic surface in the 3-sphere.

---

I guess that there could be a more elementary argument along the following lines: attach a Weinstein handle along $L$, look for a symplectic approximation of the core disk (relative to its framed boundary). You obtain a symplectic manifold with $H_2=\mathbb{Z}$, whose Chern class is determined by the rotation number (as shown by Gompf), and you can apply the adjunction formula. My guess is that if $tb(L)$ is less than $2g_*(L)-1$ (where $g_*$ is the slice genus) you have no chances.

---

Finally, one could wonder what happens if you ask for a Lagrangian surface rather than a symplectic one: in this case tb needs to be $2g_*(L)-1$ and rot needs to be 0. There's a nice [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611848) by Chantraine on the subject.

Comment: Dear Marco, I do not understand your second comment. $tb(L)<2g_*(L)-1$ would be always true by adjunction, plus I am not sure how this kind of argument will show that $L$ doesn't bound a "symplectic" surface.

Comment: as for the first comment, double brached cover of $B^4$ along surface $\Sigma$ is strong convex filling of double branched cover of $S^3$ along $T$. But that's true even if $\Sigma$ is not symplectic, isn't it?

Comment: @nikita: The adjunction inequality says that $tb(L)\le 2g_*(L)-1$, so equality is still possible, but either way if you have a symplectic surface then it actually satisfies an adjunction formula $\langle c_1(\omega), \Sigma\rangle + \Sigma\cdot\Sigma = 2g(\Sigma)-2$.  In response to your second comment, if the surface is symplectic then its branched double cover is naturally a symplectic manifold and so the contact structure which comes from taking the branched double cover of the transverse knot in S^3 is in fact symplectically fillable.

Comment: @StevenSivek: I thought it was obvious at the moment, but now it is quite unclear why this should be true. i.e. why is branched cover of B^4 over a symplectic surface naturally symplectic?

Comment: @nikita: this is very similar to what happens in the complex case. Away from the branch set, there is no problem; along the branch set, you work in local coordinates (using the symplectic neighbourhood theorem).

Comment: @MarcoGolla: thank you, I need to check the details though. This is interesting fact:  For instance, take 5-fold cover of $B^4$ over (2,3)-torus knot. this knot bounds a symplectic surface (since it is binding of an open book for $S^3$ and the page of o.b. is symplectic). Now the cover X should be symplectic. We know this is correct already since $X=-E_8$ and it carries a symplectic structure coming from the Stein structure. Also X is a convex filling of poincare homology sphere (2,3,5) since $B^4$ is convex filling of $S^3$.

Answer (score 3):

The knot must be quasipositive.  You can perturb it to be transverse as in Marco Golla's answer, and then a theorem of Boileau and Orevkov (in [Quasi-positivité d'une courbe analytique dans une boule pseudo-convexe](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0764-4442(01)01945-0), [MR1836094](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1836094)) says that transverse knots which bound symplectic surfaces in $B^4$ must be quasipositive.